# How to configure address of WSDL URL in Apache Axis2?

Tags: apache-axis, domain-name, tomcat8.5

I am using Axis2 and Tomcat8.5. My WSDL URL is :  http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/Myapp.

But i want it to configure like this: http://localhost:8080/**phase**/axis2/services/Myapp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to rename your WAR file or XML context file. E.g. if your WAR file is named axis2.war change it to **phase#axis2.war**. If you use XML file axis2.xml, rename accordingly to **phase#axis2.xml**.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Naming